# SQLite rawQuery() with WHERE clause to return count

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a method which takes certain string and search it into sqlite database. If the String exist/not exist in data base it should return int count (number of rows), How can i achieve this?

Here are my codes for that specific function, each time i run it return zero even if the specified String exist in databse.

```
public int getMsgCount(String msgQuery) {
    String countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM " + MsgModal.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + MsgModal.COLUMN_MSG  + "= '" +msgQuery +"'";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int count = cursor.getInt(0);
    cursor.close();
    // return count
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Nothing particularly wrong here (except potential SQL injection) - likely the `WHERE` just matches no rows. Can you post some evidence for "specified String exist in databse"

Comment: Thank you for your concern. I figured out that the error in String queried, now its working fine. Can you advice regarding the SQL Injection.?

Comment: Rather than putting the string inside the SQL, use `?` variable and pass its value in the `selectionArgs`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this code.

```
public int countRow(String query) {
    int count = 0;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    count = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the string is part of the column, so instead of `=` you need `LIKE`:

```
String countQuery = 
  "SELECT count(*) FROM " + MsgModal.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + MsgModal.COLUMN_MSG + " LIKE '%" + msgQuery + "%'";
```